# How to make the Queue wait in a multithreaded operation

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a Queue which i will be using in a multithreaded operation.

I want the push function to wait if the size of the queue is more than 5.

```
template <typename T>
class CAMERA_DATA_QUEUE
{
private:
    std::queue<T> m_queue;
    std::mutex m_mutex;
    std::condition_variable m_cond;

public:
    void PushItem(T item)
    {
        // Acquire Lock
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
                                            // If size is greator than 5 the function should wait.

        m_queue.push(item);
        m_cond.notify_one();
    }


    T Pop()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        // wait until the queue is not empty
        m_cond.wait(lock, [this]() {return !m_queue.empty();  });
        // Get the item
        T item = m_queue.front();
        m_queue.pop();
        return item;
    }

    void ResetQueue()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        m_queue.empty();
    }


    int GetSize()
    {
        return m_queue.size();
    }

};
```

I am not able to figure around how to do that.

Comment: Your problem breaks down to 2 sub-problems: "make push block if the size == 5" and "make pop notify waiting pushers if it causes size to go below 5". You have already solved a similar problem where you make a popper wait until the queue is not empty.

Comment: @Botje if add these two lines in the Add function that should be sufficient ?

Comment: m_cond.wait(lock, [this]() {return m_queue.size() < 5;  });
m_cond.notify_one();

Comment: Maybe. Think about it for a while and/or TIAS (try it and see). Will this behave correctly in all situations?

Comment: As addition to @Sam Varshavchik answer  int GetSize() should be under lock or private (if used only as predicate in conditional). Since each function is one big critical section your multithreaded queue will be slower then single threaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have an available condition variable. The simplest, minimal change is to redefine it its purpose in life from its current "something was added to the queue" to "something was added or removed from the queue".

So, in the push function, adding this:

```
m_cond.wait(lock, [this]() {return m_queue.size() < 5; });
m_queue.push(item);
m_cond.notify_all();  // Replace the existing notify_one with notify_all.
```

will make the pusher block if the queue is full. Something, however, has to signal the condition variable, to make this work, so, just signal it in the pop function by adding:

```
m_cond.notify_all();
```

after the popper plucks off the event from the queue. Every pop will signal the condition variable. If the queue is not full and there are no blocked pushers this will do nothing, otherwise it'll wake them up.

It's possible, I suppose, to fine tune this so that the additional signaling happens only in the precise situations where it's needed, and/or continue to notify only one blocked waiter, rather than all of them. But the correct logic gets too complicated to figure out and unless it's 100% right this'll likely end up in a lengthy, painful, chase for elusive synchronization bugs. The simpler the logic, the fewer fertile breeding grounds for bugs there will be.